# Posicionar contenido de un RecyclerView horizontal en el centro

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Buen dia, tengo problemas al tratar de posicionar el recycler el centro encontre la manera de que el recycler sea horizontal con la siguiente linea

```
rvLista = findViewById(R.id.rvListaReportes);
rvLista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

pero no encuentro forma de que el scroll se haga en el centro no arriba investigando se supone que es suficiente con este linea

```
SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
helper.attachToRecyclerView(rvLista);
```

Pero no logro el resultado en cual necesito que se posicione en el cuadro rojo osea en el centro

[image: Se deberia posiconar en el cuadro rojo osea en el centro]

Comment: Hola, es importante agregues el layout donde se contiene tu recyclerView ya que este define la posición de tu recyclerview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donde se define la posición de tu `RecyclerView` es el layout, por ejemplo puedes usar un `RelativeLayout` y definir el atributo `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, esto provocará que tu `RecyclerView` siempre se muestre en el centro vertical.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        ...
        ...
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```